# Finding an item in linear graph using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of positions denoted by X and Y. [{3,4}, {5,5}, {6,5},{7,8}]

```
public class Position    {
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

I need to find positions which will be present in the linear graph Starting 
`x=1` and `y=0`. `[{1,0},{2,1},{3,2},{4,3}, ...]`.
I do not have the list which denotes the graph. I am looking for a way to find the positions based on starting point of the graph.

I can create the list of possibilities and find the matching positions. Before I do that I want to know is there a better approach?

Comment: The formula is y = x -1. You could write <list>.Where(p => p.Y == p.X -1)

Comment: thank you. Can you please write it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The points are on a straight line. The formula for the points you mention is: y = x - 1. You can apply this formula in a where clause:

```
var x = new List<Position>();
...
var pointsOnLine = x.Where(p => p.Y == p.X -1);
```

You can do this also if you have another line or formula.

Comment: my final solution was x.Where(p => p.Y == p.X - start); This was very helpful.